# Right triangles with integer sides

Tags: geometry, number-theory, prime-numbers

Most of you know these triples:

$3: 4 :5$

$5: 12 :13$

$8: 15 :17$

$7: 24 :25$

$9: 40 :41$

More generally we can construct such triangles such as 
$$2x:x^2-1:x^2+1$$

My question is why one of the sides seems to be always prime? (When there is no common divisor)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's great that you are interested and looking for patterns, so don't get discouraged. As one of my teachers is fond of saying,

> If all your conjectures are true, you aren't trying hard enough.

So, here are first ten counterexamples:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x& 2x:x^2-1:x^2+1\strut\\\hline
8 & 16:63: 65\strut\\
12 & 24:143: 145\strut\\
18& 36:323: 325\strut\\
22& 44: 483: 485\strut\\
28& 56: 783: 785\strut\\
30& 60: 899: 901\strut\\
32& 64: 1023: 1025\strut\\
34& 68: 1155: 1157\strut\\
38& 76: 1443: 1445\strut\\
42& 84: 1763: 1765
\end{array}$$

---

*Mathematica* code:

```
listofcounterexamples = {};
For[x = 1, x < 100, x++, 
  If[Length[listofcounterexamples] == 10, Break[]];
  If[GCD[2x, x^2-1, x^2+1] == 1 && Not[PrimeQ[x^2+1]], 
  AppendTo[listofcounterexamples, {x, 2x, x^2-1, x^2+1}]]]; 
listofcounterexamples
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you see (one side always having prime length) fails for larger $x$ and is a good example of the [strong law of small numbers.](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Guy697-712.pdf) Consider, for example, $x=12$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add a comment on why your claim is probably false, even before you find any counterexamples.  Your formula
$$
2x : x^2 - 1 : x^2 + 1
$$

should be a red flag.  $2x$ is never prime for $x > 1$ because it is divisible by 2, and $x^2 - 1 = (x + 1)(x - 1)$ is never prime for $x > 2$ because it factors.  So your claim seems dubious from the start -- only $x^2 + 1$ even has a *chance* of being prime.

Comment: you're absolutely right. But as stated there is no common divisor. With your example, we ca not generate $9:40:41$ for example, because you say $18:80:82$

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  You are right.  The only possible common divisor is $2$, but still that nullifies my reasoning that $2x$ is never prime.

Comment: More generally, *all* pythagorean triples can be expressed as $2mn : m^2 - n^2 : m^2 + n^2$, where $m > n$.  To ensure the three expressions are relatively prime, you require that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime and that one is even and one is odd.

Comment: From this standpoint, $2mn$ is essentially never prime, and $m^2 - n^2$ is essentially never prime also, so the reasoning in my answer still applies.